# Finding out how many distinct functions can be made.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The problem goes as follow:

Let$ A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.$

(a) How many total functions $f : A → A$ are there?

(b) How many of the functions in (a) are one-to-one?

---

I would say only one function can be made, but that doesn't make sense to me and seems too easy. My reasoning was as follow: if it is from $A  -> A$ then shouldn't it be only one function cause it is only one set? Same idea was used for b.

Comment: There are $5$ different constant functions from $A$ to $A$: the one that sends every member of $A$ to $1$, the one that sends every member of $A$ to $2$, and so on. And that barely makes a dent in the possibilities. HINT: Suppose that you’re building a function from $A$ to $A$. How many ways are there to choose $f(1)$? $f(2)$? $f(3)$? $f(4)$? $f(5)$? In how many ways can you combine those individual choices? (Multiplication principle.) How do those numbers change if the function is required to be one-to-one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign to each member of $A$, an unique member of $A$. For $1$ there are five possibilities for $f(1)$, namely $1,2,3,4,5$. Same thing for $f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)$. There are therefore $5·5·5·5·5$ possible different functions.

If you're looking for one to one functions, think of it this way. Fix the numbers in a row $$\begin{matrix}1 &2 &3 &4 &5 \\ f(1)& f(2)& f(3)& f(4) & f(5)\end{matrix}$$

Now, since it is one to one, $\left \{ 1,2,3,4,5\right \}=\left \{ f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)\right \}$, hence you need to move around the bottom row of the matrix above. There are $5!=120$ possible permutations, hence $120$ possible one to one functions.

Comment: For the first part, do you mean that from the first function $ {1,2,3,4,5} -->   {1,2,3,4,5} $  but you can say it also goes from ${1,2,3,4,5} --> {2,3,4,5} $ and so on? creating 5 possibilities for function one and same thing goes for the rest? Otherwise I don't understand what you just explained ( sorry for that)

Comment: A function $f:A\rightarrow A$ is a rule that assigns, to each number $x \in A$, an unique number $f(x) \in A$. We can look at the function as a 5-tuple $(f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5))$. Now, $f(1)$ can take $5$ possible values: $1,2,3,4,5$. $f(2)$ can also take $5$ possible values: $1,2,3,4,5$. And so on for $f(3),f(4)$ and $f(5)$. To see what is the total number of functions (or $5$-tuples we can make), we multiply these out: $5·5·5·5·5$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does! ( it makes loads of sense as A can take 5 values you have a function for each of these values and one answer for each values). However, I don't know if this will make sense but... why can't you say f(1,2,3,4,5)? Couldn't that make sense? Assuming you're in a higher dimension. Unless I'm getting all this wrong.

Comment: Well $(1,2,3,4,5)$ is a $5$-tuple, not a number, so it is not an element of $A$. The symbol $f(1,2,3,4,5)$ is usually interpreted to mean that you're assigning something (in some set) to the object $(1,2,3,4,5)$ as a whole. It is very different from what we're doing here.

Comment: Ah I see, it would be different than describing the variable of a function. I was thinking in the sense f(a,b,c,d,e) that were replaced for a certain coordinate.

Comment: Lastly, if you don't mind ( thank you for bearing with me). What did you mean by the matrix?  The last part about the 1-1 function didn't make too much sense :/

Comment: I was using the word matrix just as a synonym for table, or array. Another way to think about it is the following: Consider the elements of $A$ as $a,b,c,d,e$, where each letter corresponds to exactly one number. Now, consider some ordering of the 5 letters, and think that the letter in the first place is $f(1)$, the second one is $f(2)$, the third one $f(3)$, and so on till $f(5)$. Now there are $5!$ such arrangements, and hence $5!$ one to one functions.